# Unable to install Java on Debian

Tags: java, debian

I just installed Debian 5.0.6, 32 bit and just can't install Java.

I thought it was as simple as

```
# apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

but this is the response I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sun-java6-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package sun-java6-jre has no installation candidate
```

Any ideas?

Comment: serverfault.com question methinks

Comment: @KARASZI, [Superuser](http://superuser.com) is probably the better fit, since it relates to a particular piece of software/hardware. [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)'s more for sysadmin of large networks/corporate-size software-install/maintenance problems.

Answer (score 2):

They are in "non-free" which you need to enable.

Answer (score 1):

makes sure you have the java repository configured in your apt respiratory list.

make sure to do an "apt-get update" before you try and install.

Answer (score -1):

```
Update the package index:

# sudo apt-get update

Install yui-compressor deb package:

# sudo apt-get install yui-compressor
```

i guess a lot of people wanted this enough they made a package for it... glad since java is a beast to maintain...